# Delete lines in textfiles matching any phrase from a large set of phrases

Tags: regex, perl

I try to write a simple thing with perl that goes through a bunch of text files in a folder and deletes every line that does not contain any number out of a set of 3000 different numbers.

To get it started, I tried

```
perl -ni.bak -e "print if /315879|315861|313956/" sometextfile.txt
```

This works fine so far. The problem is now, that it shouldn't test only three numbers, but about 3000. When I put all of them in the regex above, it seems to be truncated after some point and not every number is being searched for.

How can I solve this?

And while we are already at it, how can I iterate that line over all the *.txt files in a folder?

Comment: `3000 different number` and you're using a bunch of `|`. I think there is maybe some limit to the length of the regex. So you may need to optimise it by using character classes for example: `1[1-8]` instead of `11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18`.

Comment: Thanks, good idea, I'll work on that... there's certainly some pattern in the numbers.

Comment: `grep -f numbers.txt *.txt` ?

Comment: or `for file in *.txt; do grep -v -f numbers.txt $file > $file.stripped; done`

Comment: In windows: `findstr /G:numbers.txt *.txt`

Comment: @HamZa On a reasonable perl, the 3000 alternations shouldn't hit any limit. Only some optimizations (here mostly a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)) are too costly for very long regexes, but this case doesn't hit that limit (for my perl). If the regex is “truncated”, then perhaps the code creating that regex may be faulty. Dirk: Could you show the code creating your regex? (And give your perl version?)

Comment: I wrote that myself since it isn't too complicated... it's just
< /number1|number2|number3|.../
I'm using 5.16.3.1-32bit on Windows 7.

Answer (score 3):

Your list of 3000 numbers should work fine within the context of an actual Perl program/script.

However, in your question, you show it as a one-liner being run on the command line from a shell prompt, which means that your shell will truncate the line before giving it to your Perl interpreter.  I don't know what a typical maximum line length would be for modern shells, but 3000 six-digit numbers, plus pipes for the regex alternation, adds up to 21,000 characters, which is probably going to be longer than most shells allow by default.

Comment: Yep, this seems to be the point. I tried to run it from a shell prompt, at the moment I'm using Strawberry Perl under Windows 7.

Should I rather put the command with the long regex into a script and only run this script from the shell? If so, how do I get "-ni.bak" in there for in-file editing?

Comment: @Dirk: I can't find the documentation where it's explained, but the way the "in-place editing" actually works is by creating a new file and then, when it finishes running, it renames the original file to `original.bak` and renames the new file to `original`. You can do this in your own script with the `rename` command.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this definitely seems not to be a perl problem but is about the command shell you use. There is an official Microsoft article about the limitations on Windows systems:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/830473/en-us

However, Unix / Linux systems seem to be much less restricted concerning the maximum argument length (still depending on the actual Kernel or whatever, you can find that out on Google). When I passed my code to a friend running MacOS, he had no problem pasting it into his shell and running it properly.

So my solution will be to get some live Linux distribution and do the job there. Not beautiful, but this is gonna work for me. Still, if anybody finds a solution that can be used under Windows, I would appreciate that for future needs.

Thanks everybody.